# What are the 'chrome:' and 'resource:' protocols in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, protocol, npapi

From reading the error console, I've noticed that Firefox has several internal protocols, such as `chrome:` and `resource:`.  What are they used for, and why are they necessary?  Are they part of the [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) (which I am not familiar with)?

*This question is independent of operating system or Firefox version.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Firefox use the "chrome://" protocol / schema in URLs?](http://superuser.com/questions/517160/why-does-firefox-use-the-chrome-protocol-schema-in-urls)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox's addons include extensions, themes, language packs, and plugins.

The protocols you asked about are Firefox's internal protocols for **extensions**.

1. [The Chrome URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL)
2. [Chrome registration -- resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#resource)

NPAPI is the API for **plugins**.

[MDN: Plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins)

[MDN: Gecko Plugin API Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference)